# When i use iframe dailymotion fullscreen;.... blogger linked to my app, the video pops out from the app & when i press back button app closes

Tags: html, iframe

> When i use iframe dailymotion fullscreen.... blogger is linked to my app, the
>   video pops out from the app & when i press back button app closes?
>   what is the solution in iframes changes to be made?

Comment: please share your code

Comment: <div id="container">
<iframe onload="document.getElementById('loadImg').style.display='none';" sandbox="allow-forms allow-pointer-lock allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-top-navigation" scrolling="no" src="http://educationlevel.ml/dailymotion.php?id=x5hywa"></iframe>
</div>

Answer (score 0):

put your link in the below deshes

```
<iframe frameborder="0" width="480" height="270" src="//www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/--------?autoPlay=1" allowfullscreen="" allow="autoplay"></iframe>
```